# SVG feGaussianBlur stdDeviation value issue in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, gaussianblur

I have this SVG code in my HTML that renders a triangle with a shadow below it:

```
<svg class="svg-triangle">
    <defs>
        <filter id="shadow" x="0" y="0" width="200%" height="200%">
            <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="-1" />
            <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="2,5" />
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <polygon points="0,0 22,0 11,7" filter="url(#shadow)"/>
</svg>
```

That code works fine on Chrome and Firefox, but that's what happens when it get rendered on Internet Explorer 11, the gaussian blur stdDeviation value becomes:

```
<feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="1.65726e+009" />
```

And the shadow is obviously not showed

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Thank you

Comment: The "strange" value, 1.65726e+009 is taken directly from the DOM explorer in Internet Explorer

Comment: have you tried a space instead of a comma?

Comment: Tried with "2 5", that's working on Chrome/Firefox but on IE the value in the page is now "1.7414e+009" and is still not working

Comment: On my copy of IE11 it looks fine. Almost identical to Chrome.

Comment: There was no way to make it work so I tried this workaround that did its job perfectly, I set an "id" on the "feGaussianBlur" element and then with JS i did "document.getElementById("blur").setStdDeviation(2, 5);"